# Preservation of positivity under convergence in distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, weak-convergence

I have the following situation:

$\mathbb{P}(X_n\geq 0)=1\quad \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $X_n \overset{\mathcal{D}}{\rightarrow} X$ as $ n\rightarrow  \infty$.

How do I prove that the positivity of $X_n$ is preserved under the convergence in disribution, i.e. it holds

$\mathbb{P}(X\geq 0) = 1$?

(we are talking about real-valued random variables).

Comment: Im a bit rusty in statistics, but wouldn't $X_n : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, $X_n(x) = 1/n$ converge to $0$, where $\mathbb R$ is equipped with any propability measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on the definition of convergence in distribution you have at your disposal.

1. If it's $F_{X_n}\to F_X$ at each point of continuity of $F_X$, then take $(\delta_k)_k$ a sequence of negative numbers such that $\delta_k\to 0$ and each $\delta_k$ is a continuity point of $F_X$. Then $0=\mathbb P(X_n\leqslant \delta_k)\to \mathbb P(X\leqslant \delta_k)$, then let $k\to\infty$.
2. If it's $\mathbb E[f(X_n)]\to \mathbb E[f(X)]$ for each $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ continuous and bounded, then approximate by above the characteristic function of $[0,\infty)$ by such functions.
3. If we know portmanteau theorem, it's a direct consequence (take $C:=[0,\infty)$ as the test closed set in the statement of the theorem).